# WP jQuery conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm customizing a WordPress theme but due to some jQuery conflict some of the features are not working.

I'm using a theme already having these JavaScript files:

```
jquery.js?ver=1.10.2
jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1
jquery.flexslider.min.js?ver=3.7.1
```

Now I want to add a plugin which is using this this jQuery library:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js

But if I add both scripts then some of the theme functions stop working.

Comment: did you set them in the `functions` file? with `wp_enqueue_script`?

Comment: also make sure you are not loading jQuery twice otherwise it will give you that behaviour

Comment: wp_enqueue_script..okies I'll try this..

Comment: The theme and all the plugins MUST use the wp_enqueue_script function to add jQuery, if a plugin don't use this function adding an own version of jQuery then the plugin has to be fixed.

Comment: you can use jQuery `version 1.10+`. try using without adding `1.8.3`